# Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "native2ascii" in open jdk 9

Tags: java

I have installed open jdk 9 and when execute my ANT script , it gives the following error:

```
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "native2ascii"
```

Comment: any input for this?

Comment: Please add more information regarding ant script, what you have tried and detailed error you have got. Relevant information helps SO members to answer your queries.